# How to sort tire sizes in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort list of (strings) tire sizes from smallest to biggest.

```
['285/30/18',
 '285/30/19',
 '235/40/17',
 '315/25/19',
 '275/30/19']
```

should be sort as:

```
['235/40/17',
 '285/30/18',
 '315/25/19'
 '275/30/19',
 '285/30/19']
```

I basically have to sort the strings starting from the right, middle then left.

What I have so far (bubble sort):

```
# this sorts the first numbers on the right.
nums = list(ulst)
for i in range(len(nums)):
     for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
         if ulst[j].split('/')[2] < ulst[i].split('/')[2]:
             ulst[j], ulst[i] = ulst[i], ulst[j]
```

I now have to sort the middle without messing up the sorting on the right row, then sort the left row....

How do I solve this without creating a for/if nested mess?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python has several features that makes this easy to do. In fact, you can do it all in one statement:

```
sorted(nums, key=lambda x: tuple(reversed(list(map(int, x.split("/"))))))
```

The `x.split("/")` takes each value and makes a list of strings:

```
["235", "40", "17"]
```

Using `map(int, ...)` gives a list of integers:

```
[235, 40, 17]
```

`reversed()` turns that around:

```
[17, 40, 235]
```

and `tuple()` converts that into a tuple:

```
(17, 40, 235)
```

which, when compared to other similar tuples, gives the sorting order you want.

Comment: This underscores a tangential point: it's generally good to prefer built-in behavior like `sorted`, rather than implement your own sort function. Unless your goal is to implement a sort function, of course.

Comment: `reversed()` actually returns an iterator.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Thanks, that reminded me to check that this works in Python 3.x. I had to add an extra `list()` between `map()` and `reversed()`. `tuple()` is quite happy taking an iterable.

Comment: This is the right approach but feels a little indirect as written.  I think something like `key=lambda x: list(map(int, x.split('/')))[::-1])` or the same with `tuple` would be Py3-compatible and not have the slightly warty list->tuple conversion or six consecutive `)` characters..

Comment: Personally I'd replace `list(map(int, x.split("/")))` with `[int(s) for s in x.split("/")]`, which I consider easier to read. I *do* prefer reverse compared to `[::-1]`, so I'd end up with: `tuple(reverse([int(s) for s in x.split("/")]))`. In total 3 parens which is still quite a lot, but already better than the original 6 ;) All subjective obviously.

Comment: Thank you for breaking it apart and explaining it step by step in a succinct fashion! It works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to construct the sort key using the following `value` function which takes into account the three fields in the correct order:

```
def value(s):
    arr = s.split('/')
    return arr[2] * 100000 + arr[1] * 1000 + arr[0]

ulst = ['285/30/18', '285/30/19', '235/40/17', '315/25/19', '275/30/19']

for i in range(len(ulst)):
     for j in range(i+1, len(ulst)):
         if value(ulst[j]) < value(ulst[i]):
             ulst[j], ulst[i] = ulst[i], ulst[j]

print ulst
```

The output of that is, as desired:

```
['235/40/17', '285/30/18', '315/25/19', '275/30/19', '285/30/19']
```

This will work fine provided that your tire sizes are 3/2/2 digits as specified which is a fairly safe bet - I've never seen a tyre below 12 inches and one of 100 inches would probably be too big to ride :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the composition of [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed), and [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) to create a key function to use with `sorted`:

```
sizes = ['285/30/18',
         '285/30/19',
         '235/40/17',
         '315/25/19',
         '275/30/19']

s = sorted(sizes, key=lambda z: tuple(reversed([int(i) for i in z.split("/")])))
```

The sorted function takes a sequence and a key function, and returns a list of the items of the sequence sorted by the return value of the key function for each item of the list. This key function, `lambda z`, first splits the item on the "/" character to give a list of strings, which are then each converted to numbers, which are then passed to the `reversed` function which gives an iterator of the reverse order of the sequence passed in (NOTE: this isn't evaluated yet), and the `tuple` function evaluates the reverse iterator, turning it into a sequence that can be used for sorting.

So the a sequence of strings formatted like "a/b/c" will be returned sorted by (c, b, a). This results in:

```
>>> print s
['235/40/17', '285/30/18', '315/25/19', '275/30/19', '285/30/19']
```

Comment: Using string comparison instead of int comparisons is a really bad idea: `"19" < "2" == True`. My knowledge about tires is pretty limited though, so maybe it's fine in this specific case for all sensible sizes.

Comment: You're right, of course. I've edited it to handle this properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good answers. If you're doing this just for example sake or a quick one time parse, or a homework assignment, then they all illustrate string handling/sorting good. But if you're really building a real app around tire management, I would consider making a real model of tires, for your tires:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from operator import attrgetter

# Make a real object, because we can, and it's easy, and a real object is almost always better than abusing literal types
class Tire(object):
    def __init__(self, width = 0, profile = 0, radius = 0): #now we have meaningful names to our indexed fields
        self.width = width
        self.profile = profile
        self.radius = radius

    # let's encapsulate the '{width}/{profile}/{radius}' string representation
    # as an attribute so we can access/set it like the "real" attributes
    @property
    def description(self):
        return '{}/{}/{}'.format(self.width, self.profile, self.radius)

    @description.setter
    def description(self, string):
        self.width, self.profile, self.radius = map(literal_eval, string.split('/')) #ast.literal_eval() is safer than just eval()

    # let's make a class side instance creation method that can instantiate and set the description directly too
    @classmethod
    def fromDescription(me, descriptionString):
        newTire = me()
        newTire.description = descriptionString
        return newTire

#your original sample input     
descriptions = ['285/30/18', '285/30/19', '235/40/17', '315/25/19', '275/30/19']

#now lets make some real tire objects from those
tires = [Tire.fromDescription(each) for each in descriptions]

#make sure they still print
[print(each.description) for each in tires]

print('original sort')
[print(each.description) for each in sorted(tires, key = attrgetter('radius'))]

print('reversed original sort')
[print(each.description) for each in sorted(tires, key = attrgetter('radius'), reverse = True)]

print('width sort')
[print(each.description) for each in sorted(tires, key = attrgetter('width'), reverse = True)]

print('radius>>width>>profile sort')
[print(each.description) for each in sorted(tires, key = attrgetter('radius', 'width', 'profile'))]
```

The value of this approach is hopefully obvious at the end. We pay a bigger price up front (in terms of code space) to reify the tire objects. But once we have, we can start going nuts with sorting them all kinds of ways. The algorithms presented originally work great given certain assumptions which couple the string representation and the desired sorting output. But if you need to change your sort output, as per the last line (to sort by fields 3, 1, 2), then the handy reverse trick on tuples won't work anymore. It is far better (IMO) to separate "what it is" from how you're going to present (sort) it. And you might think of even some more clever things to do with them after that, than just sort them.

Comment: It's for a small Django app actually. I now know the best way to sort that particular set of data, the next step is actually implementing it in the models.py or perhaps sorting it per request and returning the sorted data as a serialized json set. This is a great start, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If the positions of the `/`s are constant, try:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[-2:]+x[4:6]+x[:3])
```

http://ideone.com/M6X6pW

Answer (score 0):

```
    python 3.2

    sorted(list1,key=lambda x:x[-2:])
```

Answer (score 0):

This Q/A gave me the pointers to fix my own issue - adding to let others know.
Having lists of *nix-directories in this format:
`/home/0000/Maildir/<0-255>/<userdirs>`

0000 - four digit unique provider name
<0-255> - range

The list sizes varies from 3000 to 250000 items.

I needed to sort my lists with a numeric sort on the fourth field, seperated by "/" in each item

```
sorted(a, key=lambda y: int(y.split("/")[4]))
```